# PHP mailer error: Message body empty

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I had a (until yesterday) working form in my website. The form asks some questions and sends a customized email depending on the answers. Everything was working OK, but it suddenly stopped working. Here is the error status:

Message was not sent.Mailer error: Message body empty

I´ve changed nothing these months. Maybe a server upgrade? PHP version upgrade? Wordpress upgrade? Find attached the PHP code, maybe you find something wrong with some "new standard" or version of the PHP...

```
require_once("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

// Recuperación de las variables del formulario

$duracion = $_POST['duracion'];
$idiomas = $_POST['idiomas'];
$provincias = $_POST['provincias'];
$zonas = $_POST['zonas'];
$Nombre = $_POST['Nombre'];
$Empresa = $_POST['Empresa'];
$Telefono = $_POST['Telefono'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host     = "localhost"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'presupuesto@myurl.es'; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'freelancer2'; // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
$mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
$mail->From     = "presupuesto@myurl.es";
$mail->FromName = 'my web';

//mail

$contenido = $duracion."\n".$idiomas."\n".$provincias."\n".$zonas."\n".$Nombre."\n".$Empresa."\n".$Telefono."\n".$Email;

mail("info@myurl.es","Solicitud de Presupuesto",$contenido,"From:$Email");

// resultado en funcion de la puntuación

if ($duracion == 1 and $idiomas == 1 and $provincias ==1 and $zonas == 0) {

  $mensaje = file_get_contents("http://www.myurl.es/presupuesto/2.htm");

$mail->AddAddress($Email);
    $mail->Subject  = "Presupuesto del video";
    $mail->Body     = $mensaje;

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo 'Message was not sent.';
        echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        die();
    }

  Header("Location: http://www.myurl.es/gracias");


} elseif ($duracion == 1 and $idiomas == 1 and $provincias ==2 and $zonas == 0) {

  $mensaje = file_get_contents("




...and so on!
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious conclusion is that the content you are retrieving from `http://www.myurl.es/presupuesto/2.htm` is empty, or has a problem. This is why you should always check return values.

You're also forging the From address on some messages, which will almost guarantee delivery failures.

Why are you calling `mail()` as well as using PHPMailer?

I can also see that you're using an old version of PHPMailer, so I recommend updating.

Comment: Hi Synchro, thanks for your comments! The URLs that are called for filling the message body are OK, working and with no problem. The form has also a ckecker for ensure all the inputs are well filled (from, mail, etc.). The strangest thing is that this was working perfectly until Tuesday, and stopped workind suddenly... :-(((

Comment: OK, so try it with some static content.